# How to extract a particular pattern passed in command line argument in shell script

Tags: shell

Like i am passing this argument to command line

trace.sh -f abc -t 20

i want to extrace (-t 20) in a variable. how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You can use: foo="$3 $4" and echo $foo will contain "-t 20" if the argument -t and 20 are third and fourth

Comment: @AvinashKumar: Dan Ionescu already provided the answer if the question is taken literally. However I wonder whether what you are really want, is to parse the command line options.....

Comment: @user1934428 yes i want to parse the command line options, above i gave a sample to understand. like again if the option is (-g graph -f function -t 20 -s 4). it is up to user in which order he has passed the option like any command in linux. then how should i extract -t 20.

Comment: And which shell are you going to use? Or are you free to choose one? jm666 posted an example which would work for bash, and it's certainly a good approach. I personally - but this is really a matter of taste - prefer `zparseopts`, which is available in Zsh. You find a short, but nice tutorial [here](https://coderwall.com/p/pav1uw/zsh-option-parsing-with-zparseopts).

Answer (score 0):

Very basic example (not fully error prone)

```
err() { echo "$@" >&2; return 1; }

declare -A options
options=([f]="abc" [t]="20") #the defaults

while getopts ":f:t:" opt
do
        case "$opt" in
                f) options[$opt]="$OPTARG" ;;
                t) options[$opt]="$OPTARG" ;;
                \?) err "Invalid option -$OPTARG" || exit 1 ;;
        esac
done

echo "t: ${options[t]}"
echo "f: ${options[f]}"
```